# how can I transform a long date string, not separated by any symbol, ending in several (useless ) zeroes into a dd/mm/yyyy format?

Tags: angular, date-pipe

I'm receiving these kinds of values from API: `"2019092300000000"` as a date to be properly formated: into the "dd/mm/yyyy" format.

```
// The below line of code fetches the above value from API.
this.releaseDate= this.selectedNote.dataUno["0"].releaseDate;
```

I'm trying to apply Angular date pipe transform, but I get a very weird date if I feed the pipe transform with that long string:

```
   this.datePipe.transform(
        this.releaseDate, "dd/mm/yyyy"
      )
```

this outputs this: `27/13/65952`, which is wrong.

Then I tried to store the value in a variable and apply the slice method to remove the zeroes like this:

```
 this.releaseDateSliced = this.releaseDate.slice(0, 8); // this removes the zeroes.
```

and if I print `this.fechaEmisionSliced` in console, actually I get this `20190923` which seems to be a valid value to transform using angular date pipe.

But after applying the date pipe like this:

```
 this.datePipe.transform(
        this.fechaEmisionSliced,
        "dd/mm/yyyy"
      )
```

I get this date: `01/36/1970` which obviously is wrong.

How can I accomplish to properly format the date?

Thanks.

Comment: you should be having proper timestamp atleast to get formatted date.

Comment: Your date format looks like `yyyyMMddhhmmss` and 2 extra zeros. If you need to get only date you can try to parse your sliced string with correct date format: `yyyyMMdd` instead of `dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: the extra zeros might be representing milliseconds (although it's only 2 and not 4 digits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is not a proper timestamp of seconds/milliseconds, you should parse it as a string and just build the date.

Here is one way of doing it:

```js
var dateStr = '2019092300000000';
var year = Number(dateStr.substring(0, 4))
var month = Number(dateStr.substring(4, 6)) - 1
var day = Number(dateStr.substring(6, 8)) + 1
var date = new Date(year, month, day);
console.log(date)
```